# How to properly E2E test production | consumption of messages to Kafka with NestJS and Jest

Tags: apache-kafka, jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing, kafkajs

I want to be able to test from e2e the production and consumption of messages from a NestJS application to a broker. In my case I have put up a [public repository](https://github.com/workoutInTheAbstract/nestJSKafka/blob/main/README.md) here with the problem in total.

The application uses [cp-all-in-one](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one) from confluent for the broker/schema registry and a NestJS application using the [microservices library](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka) from NestJS to facilitate the production and consumption of messages.

My specific issue in my app.e2e.spec.ts is the the inability for me to `spy on` or confirm that messages where produced to the right topic and vice versa for consumption. I can see the messages in the topic in the confluent UI as well as in logs but I am unable to confirm by automated testing in Jest.

I have tried spying on the controller that has the consumer.
Here is a snippet of the controller event handler.

```js
  @EventPattern("queuing.restaurant.ordered_hotdogs")
  async handleOrderedHotdogs(@Payload() data: any): Promise<any> {
    // console.log(`ordered dogs event handler!!!!`);
    // console.log(`buffer off the topic`, data);

    const id = await registry.getLatestSchemaId(
      KafkaTopics.ORDERED_HOTDOGS_SUBJECT
    );

    const schema = await registry.getSchema(id);

    // console.log(`here is the schema for id:${id}`, schema);

    const decodedMessage = await registry.decode(data);

    // console.log(`decoded message`, decodedMessage);
    return decodedMessage;
  }
```

Here is the test case:

```js
 test('Should produce message on GET / and then confirm production via consumption ', async  () => {

    // I want to be able to confirm that messages produced by getHello are
    // in fact produced to the right topic by 'spying on' the eventHandler
    // in the controller

    const consumerSpy = jest.spyOn(controller, "handleOrderedHotdogs");

    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Hello World!');


    expect(consumerSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);

    const expectedMsg = {
      id: "1",
      name: "Hotdog",
      topping: "pickles",
    };

    expect(consumerSpy).lastReturnedWith(expectedMsg);

    // Here to allow jest to run long enough to facilitate consumption of messages
    return new Promise((Res) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`CONSUME DEBUG`);
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        Res(null);
      }, 5000);
    });

  });
```

Here is the output:

```
> resteraunt@0.0.1 test:e2e
> jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json

 FAIL  test/app.e2e-spec.ts (14.123 s)
  AppController (e2e)
    ✕ Should produce message on GET / and then confirm production via consumption  (11335 ms)

  ● AppController (e2e) › Should produce message on GET / and then confirm production via consumption 

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      55 |
      56 |
    > 57 |     expect(consumerSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
         |                         ^
      58 |
      59 |     const expectedMsg = {
      60 |       id: "1",

      at Object.<anonymous> (app.e2e-spec.ts:57:25)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.201 s
```

Comment: Please show where `controller` is defined

Comment: Also, Nest-microservices has its own unit tests... Did you look at them? https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/integration/microservices/e2e

Comment: Most of these tests are skipped(`.skip`) because of their flakiness though, so not sure how good of an example that is